# Запуская webPack 5 в режиме development не наблюдается html страница

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Такая веселая проблема, информации на нее я не нашел. Хочу сделать под react темплейт, но что-то не получается.

**Я создал такую структуру:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Установил зависимости**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^5.66.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

**Сделал настройку webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

let configWebPack = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
    publicPath: "/dist/",
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "main.css" })],
};

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  let isProduction = options.mode === "production";
  configWebPack.devtool = isProduction ? false : "eval-cheap-module-source-map";

  return configWebPack;
};
```

**Прописал в json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Есть всего 2 инструкции, переносить css и js конечно с babel - задачами.
Кстати сам `presets`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/react"]
}
```

Это работает хорошо, **но запуск в режиме  development** отказывается получать нужные данные из  `html`

---

```
**Html структура** 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

При запуске `development` есть хост по пути `port/dist/main.js`
Но сама страница выдает `Cannot GET /`

**Консоль:**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Я вижу, что сам  `react`  выполняет свой функционал, но `html`  страницу он не видит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ребят все так печально, никто не может помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Я обратил внимания на `public` и попробовал перенести туда `html` файл, все получилось!